# how to parse XML on android

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

I am using this code to parse xml file with Java but It doesn't work with android SDK

```
   try {
        URL url = new URL("http://example.com/file.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(url.openStream());

        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

        for (int i = 1; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Element element = (Element)nodeList.item(i);
            System.out.println(element.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
        }

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException parserConfigurationException) {
    } catch (SAXException sAXException) {
    } catch (IOException iOException) {
    }
```

when i try to put the value in String the `value always = null` !!
what is wrong ???

P.S : the app has Internet permission

Comment: can you add `exception.printStackTrace` in your three `catch` code bolck, to check it has some exception happen.

Answer (score 0):

you can parse XML using some thing like that :

1. Getting XML content by making HTTP request
2. Parsing XML content and getting DOM element of xml.
3. Get each xml child element value by passing element node name.

Answer (score 0):

Depending up on the XML format, Some times we may also need to use `getTextContent()` or `getAttribute()`. Can you please try using `getTextContent` instead of `getNodeValue` once.

One more best option is to debug. Keep some debug point and check what are the childs and what is the information that the Node contains.